# Those edits from me flooding the feed

Tags: discussion, editing

As some of you may have noticed, [edits to this question](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/52267/56774) is getting bumped to the top repeatedly. This is because, due to the unreliablility of the autosave feature, I was forced to post an aswer in which I later found flaws and shortcomings, some of them serious. I feel concerned with flooding the feed with edit notifications. I want to know if there is anything wrong with it.

Comment: "due to the unreliablility of the autosave feature" - How so? I mean, what was your experience with it? The last time I tried, it remembered an answer attempt I had started writing, even though I moved from one computer to another.

Comment: (*"aswer"* → *"[answer](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/answer#Noun)*)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Pushing questions and answers to the top of the feed with trivial edits is frowned upon. There are mechanisms to warn moderators when it is happening, and we can take a number of actions, including locking against further edits.

That said, your activity is well within expected behaviour.

I did notice your edits before reading this question, I checked them out, was quickly satisfied that you were making good faith improvements, and thought nothing more of it.

So, thanks for being concerned, but all good!

Answer (score 2):

There's two main things to keep in mind while editing:

1. Make sure all your edits are an attempt to better the post
2. Make sure you're not bumping too many QA threads

You didn't fall afoul of either of these, so your edits were fine. Yes, it's pretty hard to create a disturbance when you're editing the same post in rapid succession: if someone's not actively looking at the active questions list, it's impossible for them to know if you edited the post once or many times, as a question can only appear once no matter how much activity happened.